# How to autofix serverMiddleware files using eslint in NuxtJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt.js, eslint, prettier

i'am using `@nuxtjs/eslint-module` in NuxtJS. And i have no idea how to autoformat (on server side, not editor) `serverMiddleware` files using eslint and prettier. I have installed Nuxt by `create-nuxt-app` and added ExpressJS into `~/api` folder (`index.js` and `routes/test.js`).

added to **nuxt.config.js**:

```
...
buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
  ],
...
```

```
...
  eslint: {
    fix: true
  },
...
```

**eslintrc.js** contents:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',
    requireConfigFile: false
  },
  extends: [
    '@nuxtjs',
    'eslint:recommended',
    // 'plugin:node/recommended',
    'plugin:nuxt/recommended',
    'plugin:vue/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended'
  ],
  rules: {
    semi: [2, 'never'],
    'no-console': 'off',
    'vue/max-attributes-per-line': 'off',
    'prettier/prettier': ['error', {
      htmlWhitespaceSensitivity: 'ignore',
      semi: false,
      singleQuote: true
    }]
  }
}
```

It works well and my nuxt files autofixed on save correctly, such as in ./layouts, /pages etc.
But after adding middleware (Express):

```
...
  serverMiddleware: {
    '/api': '~/api'
  },
...
```

ESLint and its plugins not watch `~/api` files for errors and dont autofixig them.
I tryed to add `~/api` folder to watch property under build options, but this do not have effect.

```
...
  build: {
    watch: ['api'],
  },
...
```

How to properly lint and autofix `serverMiddleware` files on server side not by IDE?

Comment: What do you mean by `server side`?

Comment: Looking for something like `eslint --fix --ext .js,.vue .`?

Comment: @kissu, linting and fixing should be performed on the Nuxt side, not IDE

Comment: There is no `Nuxt side` because Nuxt is only a Vue app at the end of the day. Do you mean during build time? Or before a git commit?